# nmap is unable to find all android tablets connected to network

Tags: linux, networking, android, ping, nmap

nmap is unable to find all android tablets connected to network

There are around 40 tablets connected to the same wifi in `192.168.100.0/24`. I used nmap to ping all devices in the subnet and find their ip addresses. When I run `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.100.1-254`, the result is `Nmap done: 254 IP addresses (31 hosts up) scanned in 17.55 seconds`. As you see nmap found a lot of the tablets but not all. All of the tablets have enough battery and can be reached via manual pings. Are there any other nmap commands or other tools that can find all devices in the subnet?

Comment: Does `ping 192.168.100.255` reveal any more (or different) hosts than `nmap`?

Comment: Similar question on Android.SE: [Some tablets respond to pings, others don't](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250033/44325).